# Need insert into sql if record not exist with taking data from db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Need insert into sql if record not exist with taking data from db,
i try this:

```
    INSERT INTO database.wp_usermeta(user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    SELECT (user_id, 'ur_form_id' , 210)
        FROM database.wp_usermeta ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id, 'ur_form_id' , 210
        FROM v.wp_usermeta ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

But not work, workbranch say 'whre is not valid in this position'

Comment: Even if syntax fixed, that query makes nearly no sense. More clearly explain what you're hoping to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your SQL a bit out of order; ORDER BY would go after the WHERE

```
INSERT INTO database.wp_usermeta(user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT user_id, 'ur_form_id' , 210
FROM database.wp_usermeta
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM v.wp_usermeta); 
ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

You don't need the inner order by - the exists query simply serves to decide whether any rows exist in v.wp_usermeta - it doesn't need to be ordered. In turn this causes the outer query to return a row only if there are no rows in v.wp_usermeta, and it will only insert a row if there is already a row in the table. If the table is empty, it will forever be empty. If it is not empty, then the user with the highest ID will be duplicated with those fixed properties. Is it really what you want?

If your need is instead "find all users in the database.wp_usermeta table who have no `'ur_form_id'/210` key value pair, and give them one" it might be more simply expressed as:

```
INSERT INTO database.wp_usermeta(user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, 'ur_form_id' , 210
FROM database.wp_usermeta
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM database.wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'ur_form_id' and meta_value = 210);
```

Comment: I need take last user_id and if i didn have row with 'user_id, 'ur_form_id' , 210' create it

Comment: I think it might be better to just run a query that inserts all missing users, but I'm not sure why youre using the presence or absence of rows in `v.wp_usermeta` to control whether the query runs. Did you intend for the subquery to be coordinated with the main query? Did you intend to duplicate users?

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY goes after WHERE clause:

```
INSERT INTO database.wp_usermeta(user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT user_id, 'ur_form_id' , 210
FROM database.wp_usermeta 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id, 'ur_form_id' , 210
                  FROM v.wp_usermeta 
                  ORDER BY user_id DESC 
                  LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY user_id DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I need take last user_id and if i didn have row with 'user_id, 'ur_form_id' , 210' create it

Comment: What does "last user_id" means ? With the largest value in column user_id ? Also, what if you do not have two users ?